# How to determine the number of water ligands attached to Pd in palladium chloride aquacomplex PdClₓ · yH₂O?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, coordination-compounds, spectroscopy

Normally this can be achieved using UV-vis: there is a strong absorbance around wavelength 220 nm which varies based on the number of ligands. If the palladium concentration is too high, the solution can be diluted.

However, in my case I do not know the concentration of solution as the solution is reactive. I need to measure the palladium ligands after these reactions have occurred. Thus dilution is not an option. Does anyone know if UV-vis can be tweaked or another technique for testing palladium-water speciation in solution?

FYI I get an absorbance value of 4 (the peak is still quite broad at this value) when testing the palladium chloride under the desired conditions.

Answer (score 3):

I hope the following two references would help you find the way. I honestly think Ref.1 shows much more promise, abstract of which states that:

> Monomeric palladium(II) chloro aqua complexes of the form $\ce{PdCl_r(H2O)_{4-r}^{2-r}}$ ($r = [0,4]$) were studied both experimentally and theoretically to gain insight on both the stabilities and the nature of palladium-chloride interactions.
>
> The thermodynamic stabilities of these complexes were studied in aqueous solutions from $5$ to $\pu{125 ^{\circ}C}$ with UV-vis spectrophotometry using a quartz flow-through cell. Tentative measurements up to $\pu{200 ^{\circ}C}$  were also carried out in pressurized titanium and gold-lined optical cells but revealed important losses in soluble palladium. The strong ligand-to-metal charge transfer bands of the palladium complexes below $\pu{350 nm}$ were used to constrain the step-wise thermodynamic formation constants at each temperature, using results of singular value decomposition of the spectra over a broad range of palladium:chloride ratios and wavelengths. The temperature-dependent constants were used to obtain changes in enthalpy and in entropy for each reaction. The thermodynamic stabilities of $\ce{PdCl(H2O)3^+}$, $\ce{PdCl2(H2O)2^0}$, and $\ce{PdCl3(H2O)-}$ are larger at higher temperatures, whilst the one of $\ce{PdCl4^2-}$ is smaller. All changes in entropies are positive for the former three species, but negative for the latter, presumably due to a larger solvent reorganization around the doubly charged $\ce{PdCl4^2-}$ species. The room temperature thermodynamic values derived from this study are also in agreement with previously published calorimetric data.
>
> Theoretical calculations on the intramolecular distributions of electrons in the different palladium(II) chloro aqua complexes, using the methods of atoms in molecules and of the electron localisation function, showed $\ce{Pd-Cl}$ and $\ce{Pd-OH2}$ interactions to be of largely closed-shell/ionic nature. These interactions induce an important distortion of the outer core shell electrons of $\ce{Pd}$, as well as stable accumulations of electrons between adjacent $\ce{Pd-Cl}$ and $\ce{Pd-OH2}$ bonds known as ligand opposed core charge concentrations.

**References:**

1. J.-F. Boily, T. M. Seward, “Palladium(II) chloride complexation: Spectrophotometric investigation in aqueous solutions from $5$ to $\pu{125 ^{\circ}C}$ and theoretical insight into $\ce{Pd-Cl}$ and $\ce{Pd-OH2}$ interactions,” *Geochimica et Cosmochimica Acta* **2005**, *69(15)*, 3773-3789 (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2005.03.015).
2. L. Espinosa-Alonso, K. P. de Jong, B. M. Weckhuysen, “A UV-Vis micro-spectroscopic study to rationalize the influence of $\ce{Cl-(aq)}$ on the formation of different $\ce{Pd}$ macro-distributions on $\gamma$-$\ce{Al2O3}$ catalyst bodies,” *Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.* **2010**, *12(15)*, 97-107 (DOI: 10.1039/b915753k).

Comment: Thank you Mathew! The studies themselves do not help with the problem, but they do provide good references for the regions that I should look. I might be able to avoid the dilution and just look at the secondary peaks that show up in the 400 - 500nm region.

Comment: @Nilay Ghosh: I included the abstract. My intention was to give some insight to OP and I think OP found some lights.:-)